# NotePad++ - Why does finding ^ not work?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to move away from [TextPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextPad), and I just can't get regular expressions like `^` and `$` to be replaced. I have definitely ticked the regular expression box.

What am I doing wrong?

I am trying to find the start of a new line. In TextPad, it is find '^' and ensure regular expressions is enabled. With Notepad++ it does not do that. It just says "Not found".

Comment: I've used TextPad and found this same issue to be *annoying* (to put it mildly).  Basically, Npp's Regex functionality is *stunted* when comared to most other Regex-s.  This stems from the fact that Npp is an *abstraction* of the Scintilla Editor which uses a single-line-based RegEx :( -- The Npp crew are quite well aware of this issue, but it has (oddly) been on the back-burner (a time and resources issue).  $ does work, but they haven't got ^ to work multi-line (yet). I know this limitation, and work with (and aroud it). As mentioned below ^(.) works. (Rarely, I revert to TPad or UltraEdit)

Comment: PS. you can often use *Extended* (vs *RegEx* ) as a workaround for \r and \n - this semi-mimics a start-of-line.  Also, as a by-the-way, you can stay in *Normal* search and turn on  View -- Show Symbol -- Show End of Line..  Although they don't (visually) appear in the Find-field, if you select CRLF first, the Find-field auto-prime kicks in when you press CTRL+F, and it quite happily becomes a multi-line (but not RegEx) search. Its not much different to *Extended* search, but I found it to be interesting, and some readers may also find it so. (I love Npp :)

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to find the start of a new line? Do you want to add something at the beginning of every line? That would help us actually answer the question. If you are using Notepad++ in order to move away from a paid solution, you will have to learn its quirks and work around them. I have had no problem doing this, since Notepad++ is very good in so many other ways.

Answer (score 29):

^ and $ are both *anchors* in Regex, which means if you want to replace the literal chars `^` and `$` you need to escape them, usually with a leading backslash (`\^`, and `\$`).

To find the first character on a line use `^.`

The start line anchor (`^`) is a zero-width match, so combining it with the . will find any character at the beginning of a line.

Maybe you can explain what you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same issue myself. After some trial and error you can achieve the same by doing the following:

Find: **^(.)**

Replace: ***[the string you wish you insert]*\1**

What this will do is locate and tag the first character of the line, put in the new string and put the tagged character after it.

For example, I needed to insert a single quote at the start of each line:

Find: **^(.)**

Replace: **'\1**

You can do the same for the end of the line by doing:

Find: **(.)$**

Replace: **\1*[the string you wish to append]***

Answer (score 8):

Because these are special characters that represent the front (`^`) and end of line (`$`). Try escaping them with a `\`.

Examples:

Match "Cat" at the beginning of the line:

```
^Cat
```

Match "Cat" at the end of line:

```
Cat$
```

Match "Cat" as only thing on a line:

```
^Cat$
```

Match a "$100" within a line:

```
\$100
```

[Here](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/regExpList.php) is a link for the specifics on regular expression matching within Notepad++.

Comment: The link seems to be (effectively) broken.

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

Before

- Albert@hotmail.com
- Lucas@gmail.com
- Rober_Klein@aol.com
- Fisher@zmail.com

After

- Albert
- Lucas
- Rober_Klein
- Fisher

Remove after character or text

@(.*)$

Remove before character or text

^(.*)@

```
dot = any character
asterisk = zero or more times
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it...

Before:

```
$_GET['id']; $_GET['nick'];
```

After:

```
htmlentities($_GET['id']); htmlentities($_GET['nick']);
```

So. On the **find** field put:

```
$_GET(.*])
```

On the **replace** field put:

```
htmlentities($_GET\1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been fixed now.

In Notepad++ v6.9.2 (running under Windows 7) I get both `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) to work.